# Make me a password generator!

Tags: code-golf, random

I am making a customizable password generator.

But I (for some reason) thought it'd be better to let you guys do it.

---

## Umm.. then?

You only get one integer. That will include all the information about the customization.

The first 4 bits (1,2,4,8) will be used for choosing which charsets will be used.

Each bit corresponds to:

1: Lowercase alphabet(`qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm`)

2: Uppercase alphabet(`QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM`)

4: Numbers(`0123456789`)

8: Special chars(All printable characters except ones stated above and the space)

The length of the password will be shifted 4 bits. In other words, multiplied by 16.

Then generate the password with the charsets and the length.

## Examples

```
175 (10*16 + 15 (1111)): a_U0!/h96%
```

Comment: _In other words, multiplied by 16._ I don't think that's correct. Perhaps "floor division by 16"?

Comment: Does this mean newlines are allowed in the generated password? Seems a bit unusual for a password.

Comment: Randomly? All possible passwords equally likely?

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>217</s> 203 bytes

```
from random import*
r=[10]+range(33,127)
r=[r[65:91],r[33:59],r[16:26],r[:16]+r[26:33]+r[59:65]+r[91:]]
x=input()
l=x>>4
print''.join(map(chr,sample(sum([k[1]for k in enumerate(r)if x&2**k[0]],[])*l,l)))
```

Ugh this is horribly long. The part I think could be golfed the most is the part to get the charsets; that part was a pain.

By the way, I am @HyperNeutrino; I'm just getting enough rep to chat. :P

-14 bytes thanks @ValueInk!
Bug fix thanks to @ovs!

Comment: Isn't `from random import*` shorter? Also is there anything in Python 3 that requires you to use it over Python 2? Python 2's `print` saves a byte, you can drop the `int` call around `input`, and `range` returns the list right away.

Comment: @ValueInk Right, thanks. -14 bytes total! :)

Comment: Currently 9 is in *special chars*, fix that by replacing `r[16:25]` with `r[16:26]` and `r[25:33]` with `r[26:33]`

Comment: Oh wait I just thought you were a sockpuppet of HyperNeutrino's.

Comment: @SIGSEGV I am pretty much, except this account and that won't be transferring any rep between them. :P

Comment: @ovs Thanks; I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 78 bytes

```
:2 tb _4 drop ascii'\' 'modI'toarr+match[''#`]map\keep''#`\16/~~:>$randin~2/"!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#JY7LCoJAGIX3PsXpAr8SIRNdaBbhtmdQqUkNp5oL47iKfOvWNtLmwOH7OJx85Bv4Gy5b1M5YiK6SkgoCKVOfyRvh3EoJX7U50eJaKmGLZ9PYqRRsnw4DPy2d0LXUwyadz8aSpRm/R/lN6mm0sy/phQdlhIeRukSgygcaxdsj2GGHHWMJ3tDgEUJSJmvE2V9KOAgz2N4HcofpffRB@DB@tVlXomqbHw) Takes input from the top of the stack and leaves output on the top of the stack. TIO link includes test suite (thingy) for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica 175 Bytes

```
""<>RandomChoice[(j=Join)@@Pick[c~j~{Complement[(r=CharacterRange)[1,127],j@@(c=r@@#&/@{{97,122},{65,90},{48,57}})]},(i=IntegerDigits[#,2])[[-4;;]],1],i[[;;-5]]~FromDigits~2]&
```

Coded pretty much as explained in the question. Seems like rearranging the ASCII table was expensive.

Also, there is a bug in CharacterRange which doesn't allow it to accept 0 as an argument (at least in M10.2, which is what I have handy on my laptop), so to fix that would need another 7 bytes to include the ASCII null character.

Comment: If the error you're getting is "Arguments 0 and 127 of CharacterRange are not both strings of length 1 or integers", I'm getting that on 11.1.1 too.

Comment: yep,that's the one

Comment: Infix notations can decrease a few bytes, and `@@#&/@` is just `@@@`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>127</s> 113 bytes

Jörg helped my tired brain with 10-2 bytes and I found another 2+4.

```php
for(;$i<$argn>>4;$c=chr(rand()))foreach([lower,upper,digit,punct]as$t=>$f)$argn>>$t&(ctype_.$f)($c)&&$i+=print$c;
```

**breakdown**

Run as pipe with `php -nR '<code>'`.

```php
// loop while length not reached
for(;$i<$argn>>4;
    // pick random character
    $c=chr(rand())
)
    // loop through bits and functions
    foreach([lower,upper,digit,punct]as$t=>$f)
        // if test is positive, increment length counter and print character
        $argn>>$t&(ctype_.$f)($c)&&$i+=print$c;
```

Neat tricks:
The `ctype` functions return `false` on failure (resulting in `$argn>>$t&0`, so the bit is irrelevant);
`true` on success (resulting in `$argn>>$t&1`, i.e. a test on bit `$t`).
If that test fails, short circuit kicks in and the character is skipped.
If it is positive, `$i` will be increased by the return value of `print` (always `1`).

Comment: Why eval? `$argn>>$t&(ctype_.$f)($c)&&print$c.!++$i;` should do the same - 1 Byte for `chr(rand()%127)` instead of `chr(rand(9,126))`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Ah I couldn´t remember how to do that concatenation thing. Thanks! But I don´t need that modulo: cast to char implies 8 bit, and the unprintables still get kicked by `ctype`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>93</s> 78 bytes

*Saved 15 bytes thanks to ETHproductions*

```
;>>4 o_=ApU&1©CU&2©BU&4©9o U&8©Q+"\{|}\\!#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_`" f q)gMqZlÃq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@29tZ2eikB9v61gQqmZ4aKVzqJrRoZVOoWomh1Za5iuEqlkcWhmorRRTXVMbE6OorKKqpq6hqaWto6tnZW1ja2fvEB0bF5@gpJCmUKiZ7lsYlXO4ufD/f0Nz0695@brJickZqQA)

Comment: Let's see... you can save several bytes by changing `o r_+(Y=...gMqYl}P` to `o_=...gMqZl} q`, another two by changing `r+P` to `q`, and some more by creating the range [0...9] instead of `165+"7890"+234`. (You're missing a `\{|}` from the end of the string, btw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 180 bytes

```python
lambda x,r=[10]+range(33,127):''.join(chr(choice(r[65:91]*(x&1)+r[33:59]*(x&2>0)+r[16:26]*(x&4>0)+(r[:16]+r[26:33]+r[59:65]+r[91:])*(x&8>0)))for i in' '*(x>>4))
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NY7RqsIwDIbvfYrghWt1Sru66gLuRXp20c1NK66VsAtBfGyvZyuchJA/H39ChtPffLdje7bwzOlkpGg2ZP2lZ0rlsjhwzLLdLTjPuivFCq7rGRldYiWbNXuuJN@QUQrL6jcWtUhAaiz0D@wTiBsodbxsCo1KJVFWqMskKokNT85jdHI@BAIHzmeQRVjXe84XA4UR4lfn2Nz4CDSt538fGNFKKVKKHJJO0eACHuT8BMsXimP7hm0Nr/dyF9dGOzGXD8xxPn982Ha2u/Zf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 54 bytes

```
ØBUð,ø33r126µFỌQðṁø“ııµþ’b250Rðị@ø³%16b2UTµF
¢XȮµ:⁴’µ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AWcAmP//w5hCVcOwLMO4MzNyMTI2wrVG4buMUcOw4bmBw7jigJzEscSxwrXDvuKAmWIyNTBSw7Dhu4tAw7jCsyUxNmIyVVTCtUYKwqJYyK7CtTrigbTigJnCtcKh////MTc19W5vLWNhY2hl)

**Explanation**

```
ØBUð,ø33r126µFỌQðṁø“ııµþ’b250Rðị@ø³%16b2UTµF  - nilad which returns charset
ØB                                            - yield alphanumeric characters
  U                                           - reverse to get proper order
   ð,ø33r126                                  - append char values of printable characters
            µFỌQ                              - flatten and remove repeats to get "z-aZ-A9-0[specials]"
                ðṁø                           - mold this string like ...
                   “ııµþ’b250                 - literal [26,26,10,32]
                             R                - [26R,26R,10R,32R]. All that matters is the length of each sublist.
                              ðị@             - get the elements numbered ...
                                 ³%16b2UT     - those indices we want based on the last 4 bits of the input.

¢XȮµ:⁴’µ¡ - monad with input a
 X        - pick a random element from ...
¢         - the above charset.
  Ȯ       - Print it.
        ¡ - Repeat this ...
    µ:⁴’  - floor(a/16)-1 times. (⁴ is literal 16).
```